# How to set babel to export to es4 javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am new to babel, but I want it to export the js code in AMD style but also compatible with chrome55 and IE11.

I have this

```
var babel = require("babel-core");



var result = babel.transform("let x = 1;", {
    plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
});

console.log(result.code);
```

But the output was

```
define([], function () {
  "use strict";

  let x = 1;
});
```

This is not right as there is no `let` support in IE11.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `es2015` preset to the option. Like that:

```
var result = babel.transform("let x = 1;", {
    presets: ["es2015"],
    plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
});
```

Will result in:

```
define([], function () {
  "use strict";

  var x = 1;
});
```

You should install it first:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Comment: I get `Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory`

Comment: try installing it: `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`

Comment: ok that worked, but what is `define` function? I've seen that in requireJS, does that mean I need to add a script reference to requireJS?

Comment: You asked to transform your string to a amd style and `define` is part of AMD. I don't know what you're trying to do. This is server-side. Are you trying to compile code to pass to the client? This is not the best approach.

Comment: Well, I am trying to compile client side code that runs AMD style.

Comment: If it's just that, you should write your code into a file (a source file) and then run babel from a cli to output a destination transpiled file. Then you should import this output file into a script tag into your html. What you are doing here is just for testing purposes (transform a string).

Comment: ok but I'm still not sure how I define the `define` function. Like do I import requireJS to handle that?

Comment: Yes, requireJS handles `define`. Just load it first (script tag or import it in your code if you're using a bundler).

Comment: ok, but what about this other question I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653742/how-does-requirejs-handle-triangle-imports